# How to automatically get "iTunes Music Library.xml" from website visitor's computer?

Tags: php, xml, web, itunes, social-networking

I'm currently building a social-networking site which keeps track of the artists a user has in his/her itunes library. I plan to do this by getting & parsing the .xml file associated with the user's library. I could just prompt the user to re-upload the .xml file each time he/she wants to update their artist list, but I would like to know if there's a way to have the upload done automatically each time the user visits/logs in?

Comment: Impossible for security reasons. Just think about it. You are asking to upload arbitrary data from the client to the server without the user's interaction. You'd need a dedicated service running on the client to do the sync.

Comment: That makes sense to me. But what I'm trying to do is something along the lines of Last.fm's scrobbling feature. Is there a way I can have the user download a file (some sort of executable or script) which automatically uploads his/her library xml file to a given url?

Comment: well, yes. You can tell the user to do that. The file would likely not be a PHP file then though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Java applet. That would have local file access. However, the user would need to allow you to run it, but this could be an option.

http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but according to the developer.com article, this method only works for users who are using Internet Explorer or Netscape...

Comment: Apologies, ill see if i can locate a better one.